# responsive gallery with description giving problem

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build an image gallery with description below the image. Every thing run well except when i added in a longer description, the second row goes misorder.

How to overcome this issue?

my testing site is : http://osakaairport.com/airlines/index.htm

below is the sample code: (short code due to limited by stack overflow)

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive-main {
    width: 100%;
      }
}


*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive1 {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 19.99999%;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive1 {
    width: 32%;
    
      }
      div.desc1 {
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  }

}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

</style>

<div class="responsive1">
  <div class="gallery1">

  
    <a href="china_airlines/index.htm">
      <img src="../images/airlines/china_airlines_logo.png" alt="China Airlines"></a>
    <div class="desc1"><a href="china_airlines/index.htm">Japan Airlines Japan Airlines</a></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive1">
  <div class="gallery1">

    <a target="_blank" href="../facilities/wifi.htm">
      <img src="../images/airlines/airasia_indonesia.png" alt="airasia indonesia"> </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="../facilities/wifi.htm">
<div class="desc1">All Nippon Airways</a></div>
  
</div></div>


<div class="responsive1">
  <div class="gallery1">

    <a target="_blank" href="../facilities/wifi.htm">
      <img src="../images/airlines/cebu_pacific.png" alt="cebu pacific">
    </a>
    <div class="desc1">Peach</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive1">
  <div class="gallery1">

    <a target="_blank" href="../facilities/wifi.htm">
      <img src="../images/airlines/china_airlines_logo.png" alt="china airlines">
    </a>
    <div class="desc1">9 Air</div>
  
</div>
</div>

<div class="responsive1">
  <div class="gallery1">

    <a target="_blank" href="../facilities/wifi.htm">
      <img src="../images/airlines/china_eastern_airlines.png" alt="China Eastern Airlines">
    </a>
    <div class="desc1">AirAsiaX</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to tackle this is to set the following to class `responsive1`.

```
<style>

.responsive1{
    padding: 0 6px;
    width: 19.6%; // adjust your width accordingly base on your demand
    display: inline-block; // behave as block elements inside, but inline elements outside, just like the behavior of characters
    // no need to use float:left in this case
    vertical-align: top;
}

</style>
```

Comment: resolved the problem now....really appreciated and many thanks....!!!!